# Google App Engine Launcher quits unexpectedly

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm a complete novice so please bear with me. I tried to install Google App Engine Launcher for Python on my Mac 10.5.8 but when I attempt to open it, it quits unexpectedly with the below error message. I have Python 2.7 installed. Any ideas?

> Date/Time:       2015-05-08 22:45:58.221 +0100 OS Version:      Mac OS
>   X 10.5.8 (9L31a) Report Version:  6 Anonymous UUID: 
>   3498A919-EEA6-4D63-AD76-02D63C9F8958
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000 Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Dyld Error Message:   Library not loaded:
>   /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleAppEngineLauncher
>   Reason: image not found

Comment: Do you have libcrypto installed ?

Comment: Chances are that you'll need a more recent version of Mac OS X. 10.5 was released in 2007; it's rather old.

Comment: Yes, I think I have libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib installed. I found it by typing mdfind libcrypto in Terminal. /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/util.py
/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib

Comment: You have 0.9.7, and 0.9.8 is trying to be loaded (look at the error message). You should try to install 0.9.8.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I go about doing that?

Comment: I don't know, sorry, I am not at all familiar with Apple products.